# In-App purchases available with new app. version

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

As you know. In-App Purchases need to be configured in iTunes connect. And just before changing app. status to ready to upload, you assign those purchases to the app. version.

Purchases will become available for clients only with a new version of your app.

I have an app with a web based administration system to add products along with their store ids. My app. is communicating with my db throw a web service. therefore products don't need to release a new app version to be available.

Is there a way to achieve that without uploading a new version of the app.

Comment: Upvote Question @hasan got any perfect solution?

Comment: I think there is no perfect solution for this as far as I remember. what if you play it in another way. add products with different prices as categories for example. "1 book", "2 books", "the hero bundle", "the reader bundle" "Great deal" etc .. with different prices. and u assign each of those to multiple products of urs. that could work. but u need to be careful with the names for it to not be rejected.

Comment: what do u sell in ur app? @PramodTapaniya

Comment: I can suggest proper names for u

Comment: I am selling tutorial that will video, audio or content etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the available products in iTunes connect without having to upload a new app version.  From the iTunes connect IAP management page:

"The first In-App Purchase for an app must be submitted for review at the same time that you submit an app version. You must do this on the Version Details page. Once your binary has been uploaded and your first In-App Purchase has been submitted for review, additional In-App Purchases can be submitted using the table below."

Comment: Can't find this message. My app. status is Waiting For Review now. is it related when I can see it.

Comment: And it hasn't hit the store yet?  I got to the screen by clicking on existing apps and managing the in app purchase.  From what I gather, I don't think your'e going to have any issue updating that list (without submitting a new version) once your app is released.

Comment: Right, once the app is deployed and your IAPs are approved, you will be able to modify available purchases without uploading a new version of the app.  So, the only thing you'll need to do is keep the purchases on iTunes connect in sync with what your web service is serving.

Comment: my question was about adding new puerchases without publishing a new version does that apply too?

Comment: my question was about adding new puerchases without publishing a new version does that apply too?

Comment: Thats what I'm saying.

Comment: Hello @hasan83 I am also trying to achieve what you have asked about. Were you able to make this whole system dynamic. Is it possible to add inapp purchases and make the server return the inapp purchases ID in the app and than we request the apple for inapp purchases details.

Comment: @MoeezAkram Got a solution?